# How to make empty list in initial attr of class?

Tags: python, oop

Here is a code:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     value = []
...     def method(self, new_value):
...         self.value.append(new_value)
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.value
[]
>>> a.method(1)
>>> b = A()
>>> b.value
[1]
>>> b.method(2)
>>> b.value
[1, 2]
>>> a.value
[1, 2]
```

This happens only with lists. Is the only way to deffine *value* in __init__?
How to normally define default class values in python?

**UPD**

thank you for your responses

```
>>> class B(object):
...     value = "str"
...     def method(self):
...         self.value += "1"
... 
>>> a = B()
>>> a.value
'str'
>>> a.method()
>>> a.value
'str1'
>>> b = B()
>>> b.value
'str'
```

I don't get, why list is shared but str is not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `value` you are defining is not an instance field for your class, its more like a static field. But python doesn't mind if you access this field from instances. So, even if you access this field from instances, it is not a different list for each instance. Basically, you are appending to the same list every time the method is called.

You'll have to do this

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = []

    def method(self, new_value):
        self.value.append(new_value)
```

Now you have a different list created for each instance.

*EDIT*: Let me try to explain what happens when you use a `str`.

```
class A(object):

    self.value = 'str'

    def method(self):
        self.value += '1'
```

That last line in the previous code is the same as this:

```
        self.value = self.value + '1'
```

Now, this makes it abit easier to see what's going on. First, python gets the
value from `self.value`. Since there is no instance field defined yet on `self`,
this will give `'str'`. Add `'1'` to that and sets it to the **instance** field
called `value`. This is like

```
self.value = 'str1'
```

which is the same as you'd set an instance field in the `__init__` method (in my
first snippet of code).

```
self.value = []
```

Does that make it clear?

Answer (score 6):

Define `value` in `__init__()`. There is no other way to define instance attributes.

Attributes bound outside a instance method are class attributes and shared by all instances of that class.  Hence modifications of the objects bound to class attributes affect all instances of the class, as you've noticed in your example.